# Is there a way to see the commands that would be executed based on /etc/network/interfaces stanzas?

Tags: networking, command-line, interface

The stanzas in `/etc/network/interfaces` translate to certain commands to bring up or down an interface and configure it.

Is there a way to see which commands it translates to (similar to `set -x` in a Bash script) during runtime or, better yet, without actually invoking the respective commands.

I know that the way this translates to commands differs across versions of Ubuntu (and also Debian). So it would be interesting to find out for educational purposes, pure curiosity and of course to have those commands handy when you need/want to invoke them manually.

Comment: Which stanzas exactly ? The syntax is used by the command ifconfig (or iwconfig)  + dhclient + perhaps calling an external script (pre/post-up/down).

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: e.g. `iface ... static` and `iface ... manual` including the respective sub-options. I'd reckon, if there is a possibility to do it, it's not limited to a particular type of stanza?!

Comment: those are the options for ifconfig. `ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 ...` see man ifconfig ;p

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: I have consulted `ip(8)`, `ifconfig(8)` and `interfaces(5)`before writing up my question, but none of these was conclusive about whether there is a way other than manually "reverse engineering" the stanzas into commands based on each respective version of the tools.

Comment: It is a flat file, it gets read by whatever tool (network manager, init script) you are using to configure your network, which in turn uses the lower level tools. Read the script you are using to config your network. A better question is what part of the man pages did you not understand ?

Comment: Here is a sample boot script - http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/7.0/scripts/apds18.html If you read it, it merely calls the lower level tools "/sbin/ifup ${interface}" , etc. /etc/network/interfaces itself is a flat file, data used by /etc/init/network to then call ifup / ifconfig / etc depending on what tool or script you use to configure your network.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Network Manager, to my knowledge, uses a completely different set of files for configuration. Thanks for the link, another piece of the puzzle. I still hope to see a comprehensive answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Hah, found out how to do it. I am not sure this will work equally on older versions of Ubuntu (I am running 14.04), but here is how I was able to see the commands using [`ifup(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/ifdown.8.html):

```
ifup -anv
```

which in long command line options is more readable as:

```
ifup --all --no-act --verbose
```

This should read your `/etc/network/interfaces` and show you what's going on.

However, I got a more complete result by running:

```
ifup -nv --force $(ifquery -l)
```

Since I was able to run this from an unprivileged user account, I am positive, that this doesn't attempt any weird actions, so don't be fooled by the `--force` option.

If you want to test out with another `interfaces` file, assuming you have that file's path in an environment variable `ENIFACES`, this should do the job:

```
ifup -nv --force -i "$ENIFACES" $(ifquery -l -i "$ENIFACES")
```

---

Here's an example `interfaces`:

$ cat testif

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.16.33
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.16.254
        dns-domain mydomain.net
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        dns-search mydomain.net sub.mydomain.net myotherdomain.com

auto _br1
iface _br1 inet static
        address 10.1.0.0
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        pre-up brctl addbr $IFACE
        post-up route add -host 192.168.16.1 $IFACE
        post-down brctl delbr $IFACE

auto _br2
iface _br2 inet static
        address 10.1.0.0
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        pre-up brctl addbr $IFACE
        post-up route add -host 192.168.16.2 $IFACE
        post-down brctl delbr $IFACE

iface eth0 inet6 static
        address 2000:dead:beef:4::1234:5678
        gateway 2000:dead:beef:0::1
        netmask 64
```

... and the output produced:

```
Configuring interface lo=lo (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
Configuring interface lo=lo (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
Configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
ip addr add 192.168.16.33/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.16.255          dev eth0 label eth0
ip link set dev eth0   up
 ip route add default via 192.168.16.254  dev eth0
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
Configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet6)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
modprobe -q net-pf-10 > /dev/null 2>&1 || true # ignore failure.


sysctl -q -e -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf=0
ip link set dev eth0   up
ip -6 addr add 2000:dead:beef:4::1234:5678/64  dev eth0
 ip -6 route add default via 2000:dead:beef:0::1 dev eth0
/lib/ifupdown/settle-dad.sh
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
Configuring interface _br1=_br1 (inet)
brctl addbr $IFACE
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
ip addr add 10.1.0.0/255.255.0.0 broadcast 10.1.255.255           dev _br1 label _br1
ip link set dev _br1   up

route add -host 192.168.16.1 $IFACE
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
Configuring interface _br2=_br2 (inet)
brctl addbr $IFACE
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
ip addr add 10.1.0.0/255.255.0.0 broadcast 10.1.255.255           dev _br2 label _br2
ip link set dev _br2   up

route add -host 192.168.16.2 $IFACE
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
```